# Android, cannot iterate through JSONArray inside for-loop

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop, json

I'm trying the following to iterate through each JSONObject in an JSONArray but it's not working. I check the length of the JSONArray in the Log and it gives me the correct lenght, but I can't get the JSONObject at each element of the JSONArray. Also, each element should be a JSONObject with 8 key/value pairs. Any feedback is greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
if (getMyJSONArray() != null) {

            newJSONArray = getMyJSONArray();

            try {
                // Did this because the JSONArray was inside a JSONArray
                innerJSONArray = newJSONArray.getJSONArray(0);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (innerJSONArray != null) {

                // This gives me the right length
                Log.i("innerJSONArray.length: ", String.valueOf(innerJSONArray.length()));

                for (int i = 0; innerJSONArray.length() < 0; i++) {

                    try {

                        // This doesn't work
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = innerJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        // This doesn't work either
                        JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(innerJSONArray.getString(i));

            …(more code below to use if the part above works)

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop `innerJSONArray.length() < 0;` should be `i < innerJSONArray.length()`.

Then this line should work as expected:

```
JSONObject jsonObject1 = innerJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how glanced by that. I fixed it, now it works.